# Import .obj with texture, where texture is more photos

Tags: texturing

I just downloaded an object and it has come with a folder containing lots of pictures, as texture, but when i import it in Blender it goes all white. How can i import the texture also?

Comment: you can use the search box at the top to access commonly asked questions. start here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures/

Answer (score 0):

Make sure image search is checked. It may have material id's and if you could import as an .fbx you would probably get your textures. But, you can solve this manually yourself by using ctrl+shift+t with user interface keymap settings inside the shader editor to automatically have cycles setup anything other than gloss maps and ao maps without you having to do anything else. It does not take long.

Answer (score 0):

The .obj file must correctly specify the texture files to use, and their path.
Some software includes the full path to the texture file, which may not be the same on your system.  Edit the .obj file in a text editor to correct the paths, if necessary, or as TheMuffinMan says, (previous answer), ensure that "image search" is checked when you import the model. It's on the import .obj dialog.

Alternatively, the .obj file may be accompanied by a .mtl file (material definition file).
To use this:

1) the .obj file must specify that it uses it

2) the .mtl must have the correct paths for the texture files.  If the "image search" option doesn't work, you could try editing the .mtl file.

The .mtl file is a standard text file, which you can open in Notepad or other text editor.  Very often, the paths to the texture files is absolute (such as "E:/3DModels/wood/oldbeam.png"), and is very unlikely to match your own setup.
Edit the paths before importing the object.  If they are in the same folder as your object, just remove the path, leaving only the filename (e.g. "oldbeam.png"), or of they are in a sub-folder, include that part only (e.g. "textures/oldbeam.png")